# Is this the correct way to enqueue style sheets from parent theme and then from child theme in wordpress?

Tags: actions, child-theme, wp-enqueue-style

I am creating a child theme of a theme in WordPress. In Parent theme i have style.css and inside css folder of parent theme i have a base.css file ( and some more css files but the problem is only with base.css file ). Somehow it turns out that the sequence in which styles should be loaded is **parent->base.css** then **parent->style.css** the **child->style.css**. I want to ask whether the code below is correct way to do so ? To be specific it's **Enough Theme**.

> **functions.php inside child theme**

```
<?php
    function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

        $parent_style = 'parent-style';
        wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array('enough_base') );

    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles', 9 );
?>
<?php
    function enqueue_child_theme_styles() {
      wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array($parent_style) );
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_child_theme_styles', 11);
?>
<?php
```

Comment: You can use `@import` in style of your child-theme for inheriting style. Here, is the link to get more details on child theme creation. https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: @Amit Chauhan yes but in codex it is mentioned that enqueuing way is more efficient and correct way to load style sheets from parent theme

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code. I think there is no need to use `wp_enqueue_scripts` twice to enqueue the parent and child theme style sheets separately. Also the use of  `echo get_stylesheet_uri( );` in the `enqueue_child_theme_styles` function doesn't make any sense.

```
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'styles';

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array('enough_base') );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
```

Make sure that you replace the `parent-style` with the same `$handle` used in the parent theme when it registers its stylesheet. You can refer following link for more details. https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: The echo statement was for debugging purpose ... edited. Now the problem is that i want the specific order that i mentioned in the question ... base ->parent_style -> child_style. When i try to do it any other way that sequence comes out to be different.When i am using the code you have put in answer child's stylesheet loads before parent's. So changes i make in child's stylesheet won;t reflect.

Comment: @Desperado - I have tried that above code in my local environment and it is working as expected. Can you share link of your website? If possible. Also, I hope that you have replaced parent-style with handle of your parent theme.

Comment: I am using enough theme in my local enviornment . Could you try if possible !!!

Comment: @Desperado - I have edited the code and also added my comments regarding edits. Please check.

Comment: The problem is still the same ... child theme's style css loads earlier than parent's style css.
But with the code that i have put in question things happen correctly. But i don't know whether that is the correct way or not.